# Remove chapter number from \backmatter

Tags: header-footer, thesis

In my thesis, I have defined some backmatter. When, I do this, the backmatter (e.g. summary) takes the chapter number from previous chapter. I do not want any chapter number in the header. But I want to leave the name of the backmatter, i.e. summary in the header as it is defined now.

The code is provided below - I did not include the details of individual chapter.

```
%---------------------Preamble---------------%
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,9.5pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[total={13cm,19.5cm},top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm, includefoot]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}          % removes extra spacing between text
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\pagenumbering{gobble}          % Remove page numbers in a section. The counting starts from Introduction
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % fancy heading style in headers and footers
\usepackage{footnote}           % use with savenotes to show footnotes % footnotemark can be used when you have to use the same footnote twice (to avoid repetition)
\usepackage{graphicx}           % include graphs/ figures  in the file
\usepackage{setspace}           % to set the line spacing in the document
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}             % to write pages in landscape environment
\usepackage{threeparttable}     % to add footnotes to the tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}    % to create some space between table caption and table, otherwise there was no space
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}     % to underline the text
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\let\newfloat\relax
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{grffile}            % to avoid printing the figure name (or otherwise, give figure names without spaces)
\usepackage{float}              % figures as 6 (a), 6 (b) etc.
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}  
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\bibsep}{3.05pt}     % spacing between different references
\def\bibfont{\scriptsize}       % fontsize of the references
\usepackage[                    
singlelinecheck=false 
]{caption}

%---------------------To create fancy chapter title---------------%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}     % here change huge or large to get small or large fonts in chaptertitle
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Large\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

%---------------------Document starts here---------------%
\begin{document}            % the document starts here!

%---------------------Table of contents---------------%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{onehalfspacing}          % here doublespacing can be used. Adjust the margins of the page!
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}        % to display a detailed table of contents with each subsection
\tableofcontents
\end{onehalfspacing}
\pagestyle{empty}
%---------------------Adding space in the whole thesis---------------%
\cleardoublepage
\begin{spacing}{1.15}
%\sectionfont{\noindent\fbox}  % makes a box around the section title.

%---------------------Headers, Footers and Page numbers---------------%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %      % to add the top border
\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{5}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

%---------------------------------------------------------%


%---------------------Chapters in the thesis---------------%


\mainmatter
\include{chapterone}
\include{chaptertwo}
\backmatter
\include{summary}
\include{acknowledgements}

%---------------------Chapters in the thesis---------------%

\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for "not including the individual chapters"; in the future, add the [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) package and use `\chapter{name}\lipsum[1-50]` to generate some dummy text for a number of chapters. Alternatively, use the [`blindtext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package together with `\blinddocument`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already define the `\chaptermark` to condition on whether or not you're in the main matter (leaving out the prefix `Chapter \thechapter` conditionally), it seems sufficient to use

```
\backmatter
\fancyhead[LE]{}
```

which clears the `L`eft `head`er on `E`ven page from the phrase `Chapter \thechapter`.

Comment: I edited my question and the code. For some reason, the solution you provided, changed the header of the whole thesis and not only the backmatter.

Comment: @abhishek: I suggested you place the `\fancyhead` update *after* `\backmatter`. It will only affect the output from then onward. Your code edit removed `\sectionmark` and `\chaptermark` entirely... I don't understand why you did that? My mention of "seems sufficient to use" implied that you use my suggestion *in addition to* your existing `\chaptermark`.